# Virtual Host on Top Level Domain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to route a top level domain through Apache Virtual Hosts, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.net
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tgc
</VirtualHost>
```

`www.mydomain.net` works perfectly. But `mydomain.net` continues to route to `/var/www`. I've tried suggestions here and many different combinations, but nothing seems to work.

```
apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server mydomain.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost mydomain.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost mydomain.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:54)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Did you define it somewhere else? Post the output of `httpd -S`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah that doesn't look right... but I don't know how to fix it. Edited to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined two virtual hosts for your domain, and so only one of them is used. Fix this by removing one of them.

Comment: Yup. I had to change the DocumentRoot on the main VirtualHost to the correct path. This server is hosting many different subdomains and I did not think of that.... Thank you.